# How can I dynamically change content (text) with the click of a button

Tags: database, button, dynamic

I'm trying to build a something where I have some text, and if i want to see some different text, I click the button, and new text appears from a database or an array ( i don't know which is best for this scenario). I would potentially have a list of 100 or more snippets of text, with only one shown on screen at a time, clicking a "next" button would show a different snippet of text at random. But where or how do I store the snippets, and how do I call them on to my html page.

I was first trying to store them in a database, and then I tried storing them as php variables and then I realized even if I figure out where to store them I don't have a clue how to call them back to display them.

I've hit the limit of my programming skills and I need to reach out for someone to point me in the right direction. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: which database was tried? what did you not like about it?

Comment: MySQL? I’m not sure how to store my snippets of text, as each one would have its own class or family an different tags associated with it. So how can I store dozens of classes, each with hundreds of snippets of text each with 20 different tags.

Comment: Good realization of the difference of SnipText vs Tag1/Tag2/Tag3...  An un-normalied approach would have it all in ONE table of 22 columns SnipID, SnipText, Tag1, Tag2... with each tag being yes or no -->does the text apply to the tag.  A Normailzed approach which is very extensible would be 3 tables.. 1= SnipID, SnipText,  2=TagID, TagTypeText,  and a join table 3=TagID, SnipID.